# TypeScript Interface incorrecly extends interface. Types of property 'then' are incompatible

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Before voting down for unknown reasons, please read my profile or explain, help to edit the question or asking me for further information. That would even help me further.
I searched stackoverflow and googled the internet, but I didn't find any solution

I am trying to create an angular app with typescript but when I try to build:

> typings/angularjs/angular.d.ts:1419:15 - error TS2430: Interface `'IHttpPromise<T>'` incorrectly extends interface `'IPromise<IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<T>>'`.
>         Types of property 'then' are incompatible.
>
> tsc --version
>   message TS6029: Version 1.5.3

bower.json

```
{
  "name": "AngularTypeScript101",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.4.0",
    "angular-route": "~1.4.0"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "none",
    "target": "ES5"
  },
  "files": ["app.ts"]
}
```

I must use Angular 1.4. This is also my first typescript project. Please help.

Comment: Is it possible that promise chaining didn't exist in AngularJs 1.4? I remember back when I worked with this library and there was a point where you could call 'success' instead of 'then' on a promise.

Comment: Hi @Mickers. I don't know but perhaps tsc 1.5 doesnt work with angular 1.4. What do you think?

Comment: In my opinion I'd never use anything lower than 1.5.6 in AngularJs as that's when components came into play. Currently the latest version is 1.7.8 but I'm not sure what all has changed.

Comment: I have to use 1.4 because of legacy

Comment: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47937374/ihttppromise-incorrectly-extends-ipromise-with-typescript-2-5) which may solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Install a newer version of your typing file. You can find one [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/angular).

Comment: I will accept your answer but you  should provide a example to how   to get the latest version for angular 1.4 in my case. thanks